# How to set a flag at node when user view node?

Tags: nodes, users, flags

I have a content type 'page'. When a user views this node, I want a flag to be set automatically not by flage module link.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module seems like a no brainer to me to get this to work, with no custom module(s) needed ...

Here is how your custom rule should look like (a kind of getting started with Rules):

- Rules Event: When viewing content.
- Rules Condition: Check the content type that matches your needs.
- Rules Action: Flag the node being viewed by the current user.

Ps: I'm assuming this is about D7.